Why does any theory expanding $T^*$ have the witness property?
I was reading a proof of Lindenbaum's lemma that went like this:


Lindenbaum's lemma:
Let $T$ be a finitely satisfiable $\cal L$-theory. Then there exists a language expansion $\cal L \subseteq L^*$ and $T \subseteq T^*$ such that $T^*$ is a finitely satisfiable $\cal L^*$-theory and any $\mathcal L^*$-theory extending $T^*$ has the witness property.

The definition of the witness property the author uses is the following:

An $\mathcal L$-theory $T$ has the witness property, if for all $\phi(v)$, if $\exists v \phi(v) \in T$ then there exists a constant symbol $c$ such that $\phi(c) \in T$.

The proof goes (without much detail) like this:

Let $\cal L_0 = L$. Assume that $\cal L_i$ is already defined. For each $\cal L_i$-formula $\phi(v)$, let $c_\phi$ be a new constant symbol. Then:
$$\mathcal L_{i + 1} =\mathcal L_{i} \cup \{c_\phi : \text{$\phi(x)$ is an $\mathcal L_i$-formula}\}$$
Let $T_0 = T$. Assume that $T_i$ is already defined. Then, we define:
$$T_{i + 1} = T_i \cup \{\phi(c_\phi) : \text{$\phi(x)$ is an $\mathcal L_i$-formula and $\exists x \phi(x) \in T_i$}\}$$
Then $\mathcal L^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathcal L_n$ and $T^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} T_n$

I get why $T^*$ is finitely satisfiable, and I get that $T^*$ has itself the witness property as I defined it. But I don't understand why any $\mathcal L^*$-theory expanding $T^*$ would have the witness property. Why is this true?

They wrote extending, not expanding (i.e. there are more sentences added but the language stays the same), if that's the confusion.

uhh, actually on reading the details more closely, this seems badly busted. In order to do it this way, you need to iterate, alternating completion and expansion by constants.

Could you elaborate a little bit more on that @spaceisdarkgreen?

Not at this second, but maybe someone else will... if nobody has later, I'll write something. (You can look at, say, the proof in Marker, which uses a slighlty different notion of the witness property, and a similar construction, where it really does settle it "for good".)

Thank you. I know I could just use another definition of the witness property (for example, the one that Marker uses in his book). But I really want to make this work with this notion of the witness property. @spaceisdarkgreen

As written, this proof isn't correct.  Take $L = {R}$, where $R$ is a unary relation symbol, and $T = \emptyset$.  Then as we go through the construction written here, each $T_i$ will still be empty, so $L^$ will be $L$ together with a bunch of constant symbols, and $T^ = \emptyset$.  Then $T^* \cup {\exists x R(x)}$ is an extension of $T^*$ and it does not have the witness property.

Do you see any way of fixing the construction? @ChrisEagle

As mentioned by Chris Eagle in the comments, this doesn't work: for instance,  if you start the construction on the empty theory, you just get the empty theory back, and while this does technically have the witness property, adding pretty much anything will break it.
For the completeness theorem, the other property you need is for the theory to be a maximal finitely satisfiable theory, and there's a standard proof by Zorn's lemma that any finitely satisfiable theory can be extended to a maximal one. When the theory is of this form, either this form of the witness property, or the (in my experience) more common one where we demand all the formulas like $\exists x\varphi(x)\to \varphi(c)$ are there will suffice for the model construction. The question is how you get there.
In the more common version (as seen in Marker), you can just run one "Henkinization" step where you end up with a theory as described in the lemma at the top of your post, and then maximizing this gives you what you need. If we want to use the version of the witness property you wrote down, the strategy needs to be a little different.
The problem is, due to the problem I mentioned initially, we want to add witnesses to a theory that's already complete to get something close to what's intended, but doing so expands the language, so doesn't preserve maximality. The solution is the useful technique of "iterating to closure", which is already used when adding the witnesses.
Let $T_0$ be your initial theory, then extend it to a maximal finitely satisfiable theory. Then run the procedure described in your post to expand to a theory $T_1$ with the witness property. Then repeat the same two steps on $T_1$ to get $T_2$, and then again to get $T_3,$ and so on. Then let $T^*= \bigcup_n T_n.$
$T^*$ has the witness property and is maximally finitely satisfiable: If $\exists x\varphi(x)\in T^*$ then it's in some $T_n$ and there was a $\varphi(c)$ added on the next step. And given any $\varphi$ in the language of $T^*,$ it is in the language of some $T_n,$ so either $\varphi$ or $\lnot\varphi$ was included in the next step. The individual steps preserve finite satisfiability, so by induction, each $T_n$ is finitely satisfiable, and any finite number of sentences in $T^*$ need to all come from some $T_n$, so $T^*$ is finitely satisfiable.

As a side note, to make this work, the "adding witnesses" phase doesn't need to be as complicated as in the passage... you can just do one mini-step of it and add witness constants $c$ and $\varphi(c)$ axioms to all existential formulas in the theory at that time... no need to iterate to closure at this juncture.

I don't really understand the part about completeness theorem and maximal finitely satisfiable theories. What is the point of all that? If you take a partial Skolemization by adding axioms of the form $\exists x\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi(c_{\varphi})$ (instead of $\varphi(c_\varphi)$ whenever $T_i\vdash \exists x\varphi(x)$ as in the construction described by OP) just work?

Ah, I think I get it now. You mean that if we do exactly the same as what OP says but also at each step choose a completion of $T_i$, then we end up with a complete theory, so $T_i$ does in fact decide whether $\exists x\varphi(x)$... Well, that is a technically correct proof, but it is also very wrong on several levels, in my opinion.

@tomasz if you read the comments, op was explicit about not wanting to do it that way. What you suggest in your answer does not have the witness property according to their definition.

Is he? I've read the comments, but I don't really see how this is really so explicit. I guess the difference you are referring to is that the $T^*$ I give does not explicitly contain the formula $\varphi(c_{\varphi})$, it only implies it. Is that what you mean by not satisfying OP's definition?

@tomasz Yes, that's all I mean, though one has to be a bit careful about "implication" before the compactness theorem is proved (of course there's still a perfectly reasonable way of making sense of it). I mentioned the way used by Marker (and most people it seems) and they said they understood that and wanted to use the other definition.

@tomasz I'm not sure I agree this alternative is "wrong", though as I alluded at the bottom, it doesn't really make sense to literally use their exact construction in the iteration (I suspect that whoever wrote this was just trying to do the "usual way" while using the other notion of witness property, not realizing it doesn't work). For instance, see Alex here who mentions it's useful for handling the case where models can be empty, though I think that's reasonably easy to handle as a corner case.

I think the definition given in OP is perfectly sensible if you define a theory as something that is closed under logical consequence. Then it is equivalent to the "usual" definition that I suppose Marker gives.

@tomasz Logical consequence doesn't work right till you have the compactness theorem, though. If there's no models, everythings's a logical consequence. (But you can make it 'finitary' in a suitable way.)

I don't see what models have to do with it. This is a purely syntactic notion. And this is how theories are defined sometimes. It definitely was like this in my logic course, and I'm sure I could find textbooks that do that.

@tomasz If we're doing the completeness theorem and using deductive consequence, sure. If we're doing compactness theorem and using semantic consequence, then it would need to be modified for it to work right, until the compactness theorem (e.g. say something is a "semantic consequence" if there's a finite subset of the theory such that all models of that finite subset satisfy that something)

@tomasz Agree, it's conceivable that they developed things syntactically first and defined theories as deductively closed... what I really should have done is (as I often do), demanded that the OP produce a reference to this proof they're reading.

Frankly, I can hardly think of a context in general model theory where it would be relevant to consider $\in T$ as opposed to $T\vdash$ without assuming that $T$ is closed. Maybe if you cared about some effective aspects or something, but passing to completions is hardly effective anyway. But I concede that this answer does have a merit if you literally stick to OP's wording.

That said, I wonder if this completion is (provably) necessary if you literally want to work with these definitions (without assuming that theories are closed). I guess probably yes, by some argument involving the Tarski-Vaught test...

The solution suggested in spaceisdarkgreen's answer works, but there is a solution which, in my opinion, is much simpler and more elegant.
You can do exactly the same steps as you describe in your question, but set $T_{i+1}=T_i\cup \{\exists x\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi(c_\varphi)\mid \varphi(x)\in\mathcal L_i\}$.
Then setting $T^*=\bigcup_i T_i$ you get a theory which is very easily shown to be consistent (in fact, it is conservative over $T$: every model of $T$ expands to a model of $T^*$) and trivially has the witness property.
(If you want to avoid the axiom of choice, this is still fine - I'm pretty sure that every finite part of $T^*$ is easily checked to be a conservative expansion of a finite part of $T$, although I confess I have basically no experience with choice-less model theory, so don't quote me on that.)
In fact, I believe a simple recursive argument should show that $T^*$ is universal in the sense that if $T^{**}$ is any other expansion of $T$ satisfying the conclusion of the lemma, then $T^*$ is a reduct of $T^{**}$.

Note/edit: This answer assumes that a theory is by definition closed under logical consequence (and in the equations $T_i=...$, we implicitly close the right hand side under consequence). Alternately, it also works verbatim if in the definition of witness property we replace $\varphi(c)\in T$ by $T\vdash\varphi(c)$. It also assumes that the structures (or sorts in the multi-sorted context) are nonempty, but this can be easily worked around by replacing constants with unary function symbols.
